# How can i delete html tags

Tags: php, html, tags

im using php and i wanna know how to delete when `<p><a><img></a></p>`

from this:

```
<p>
    <strong>Lorem</strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor
    <a href="xxxx" target="yyy">sit amet
    </a>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
</p>

<p>
    <a href="xxx" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
    </a>
</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>
    <strong>Lorem</strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor
    <a href="xxxx" target="yyy">sit amet
    </a>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
</p>

<a href="xxx" target="_blank">
 <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
</a>
```

i just wanna delete tag `<p></p>` when `<p><a><img></a></p>`
i've tried using preg_replace(); function but i cant get it could you please help me, thanks

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: preg_replace() with `/<\/?p>/`

Comment: Is it a real HTML document? If yes,then why not use js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = <<< EOFHTML
<p>
    <strong>Lorem</strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor
    <a href="xxxx" target="yyy">sit amet
    </a>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
</p>

<p class="foo">
    <a href="xxx" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" height="xxx" src="yyy" width="zzz" />
    </a>
</p>
EOFHTML;


$html = preg_replace("'(<p[^>]*>)([^<]*<a[^>]*>[^<]*<img[^>]*>[^<]*</a>[^<]*)(</p>)'sim", "$2", $html);


echo $html;
```

Comment: thanks but i wanna delete tag `<p></p>` when <p><a><img></a></p>

Comment: i have another doubt i again i wanna delete <p></p> i have this:                                                                    '<p><a><img></a><div></div><p>'                                                                i use:
'preg_replace("'(<p[^>]*>)([^<]*<a[^>]*>[^<]*<img[^>]*>[^<]*</a>[^<]*>[^<]*<div[^>]*>[^<]*</div>[^<]*>)(</p>)'sim", "$2", $string2);'                           but i cant delete that tag, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use this but note that it will only work when you have `<p></p>` with no `class` or `i`d or any other `attribute` like `<p class="myclass">`(not work for this).

```
<?php
$text ='<p>
   <a href="http://xxx" target="_blank">
       <img alt="xxx" height="xxx" src="xxx" width="xx" />
   </a>
</p>';
$text=str_ireplace('<p>','',$text);
$text=str_ireplace('</p>','',$text);
echo $text;

?>

`str_ireplace` `function` returns a string or an array with all occurrences of search in subject (ignoring case) replaced with the given replace value.
```

for more info read http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: thanks but i wanna delete tag `<p></p>` when <p><a><img></a></p>

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5+ comes with a built in DOM Parser. 
[PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

It can be used to find, remove, and add elements.